# Is having a factory in C++ supporting two platforms (win32 + linux) ok?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have a socket class which is derived from an interface (iSocket), but the implementation in Win32 and Linux is different, is it ok to have the following factory:

```
class SocketFactory
{
public:
    SocketFactory();

    iSocket *CreateSocket();
};

iSocket *SocketFactory::CreateSocket()
{
#ifdef Win32
  return new Win32Socket();
#else
  return new LinuxSocket();
#endif
}
```

I wasn't sure if this was correct in the world of design patterns.

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: It may be borderline OK but it reeks of Java-ish over-engineering. Why not use conditional compilation to choose the correct platform implementation statically? It’s not like they can ever be used concurrently in the same executable.

Comment: Agree with @KonradRudolph: if the implementation is mutually exclusive platform dependent, just compile the right one with a unified name.

Comment: You could do that or since you have to build for a specific target platform anyway you could also have two different implementation files for each platform and use pre-processor conditions for building the correct implementation for the target platform

Comment: @KonradRudolph Have the #ifdef around the include and call them the same name?

Comment: @PaulMorriss Yeah, exactly.

Comment: @PaulMorriss the underlying issue is that the Win32 implementation won't compile on Linux anyway. So then why bother adding the platform specific code in multiple places? Just ensure there's a working Socket class and reference that one everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes logic defies me :)

Comment: Windows and Linux both support the BSD sockets API so the network code should be very close to the same.